# How to turn this Matrix into a list of integers?

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

I am trying to extract a list of integers from a input that looks like this:

```
[[matrix([[0.57863575]])], [matrix([[0.57170157]])], [matrix([[0.44320711]])], [matrix([[0.37195535]])]]
```

I am trying to get an output like so:

```
[0.57863575,0.57170157,0.44320711,0.37195535]
```

What are my options?

Comment: a for loop or a list comprehension

Comment: I am unsure about how to turn the matrices into numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop comprehension:

```
from numpy import matrix
l = [[matrix([[0.57863575]])], [matrix([[0.57170157]])], [matrix([[0.44320711]])], [matrix([[0.37195535]])]]

[e[0].flat[0] for e in l]
```

output: `[0.57863575, 0.57170157, 0.44320711, 0.37195535]`

The real question is, **how did you get this format in the first place?** It might be better to fix it there.

Comment: We had to add random functionality to the code our prof gave us. So I dont know how we got here

Comment: Also I got ```[[0.5786357492614388], [0.5717015739188762], [0.44320711190176887], [0.37195535304420724]] ``` as the output for some reason

Comment: But I flattened it and it seemed to become a list of integers